# (Spring Integration) Can I use the message received from a HTTP-oubound-gateway to respond to a HTTP-inbound-gateway?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have my ESB, a client and a web service.
The client send a HTTP request to ESB, the ESB to respond has to send an HTTP message to the web service:

```
>     <http:inbound-gateway id="httpInboundGateway"
>           request-channel="receiveChannel" reply-channel="outboundChannel" name="/inboundChannel.html"
>           supported-methods="GET, POST" request-payload-type="java.lang.String" reply-timeout="50000"
> header-mapper=""/>
```

...

```
   <http:outbound-gateway url="{destinationAdress}"
            request-channel="outputLevel1Channel" reply-channel="JsonTransformationLevel1Channel" extract-request-payload="true"
            http-method="POST" expected-response-type="java.lang.String" >
            <http:uri-variable name="destinationAdress"
                expression="payload.getDestinationAdress()" />
        </http:outbound-gateway>
        <int:chain input-channel="JsonTransformationLevel1Channel"
            output-channel="outboundChannel">
            <int:json-to-object-transformer type="it.model.ClientRequest">
            </int:json-to-object-transformer>
            <int:transformer ref="clientRequestToRequestTransformer"
                method="transform">
            </int:transformer>
            <int:object-to-json-transformer />
        </int:chain>
```

When I create the message to send to the client, I send it to "outboundChannel", the reply channel of the Inbound HTTP gateway.
The client doesn't receive any message.
This is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <display-name>spring-http</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>webapp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>webapp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/inboundChannel.html/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Thanks.

Comment: First step is to turn on DEBUG logging and follow the message(s) through the flow. If you still can't figure it out post more details by editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem updating Spring integration version from 2.2.4 to 4.2.0 version. Thanks.